# Operator Graph Question

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T$ be closable. I am trying to show $\Gamma(\overline{T}) \subseteq \overline{\Gamma(T)}$. I can already show the reverse inclusion. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to use the sequence definition of the closure? I mean, if $x_n\in D(T)$, $x_n\to x$ and $Tx_n\to y$, then $x\in D=(T)$ and $Tx=y$?

Comment: Can someone clarify this notation?